# How to create a requirement check/validation dialog with WiX?

Tags: wix

I am trying to create a validation dialog in my installer similar to this:

[image: http://s11.postimg.org/bvapvqour/Sql_Server_Support_Files.png]

I can't find any documentation or samples that are trying to achieve anything similar.

I am using wix toolset 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a setup bootstrapper with the UI you want.
We achieve this functionality by using WiX Burn and WPF UI.

For example, see WiX sources: Setup\WixBA

Comment: I'm sorry, i do not need it for requirement checkups, but as a validation after the user set some properties to make sure the installation will be successful.

Comment: You may be missing the point of the answer. If you want a dialog that looks like that, then you write it with WPF and it'll do whatever you want - it's your code. It's also not clear why you're validating there - all the validation I've seen takes place when the user enters a value and if it's invalid the Next button is disabled and an error message shown. Why would you let a user enter a bunch of invalid properties then show a dialog later saying that some of them are wrong?